# android phone or tablet as pc speaker over bluetooth

Tags: audio, bluetooth, desktop, android

I'd like to use my Samsung galaxy 2 exhilarate (or Archos 101 internet tablet) to play live audio from my computer over Bluetooth. WiFi is not an option since I always get disconnected and when I am connected I have weak signal.

I've looked around for solutions but nearly everything lets me play live audio from my computer to an android device - I am looking for the reverse.

How would I do this?

Comment: Please be respectful to the community we're offering to help. Please consider re-wording your question.

Comment: i was just filtering out the annoying spam and keeping the stuff from people trying to actually help.

Comment: It might help to say what you're using now for this, so that people don't suggest the same thing you are using now - or what you've looked at and why it dosen't work. Also, is this for music, or for general audio streaming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that such an App doesn't exist. What you search for is an App that transforms your Smartphone (or Tablet) into an A2DP sink (that receives the Audio from a A2DP source).

If you're interested in building such an app or you might want to know why there isn't yet such an app, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557933/receive-audio-via-bluetooth-in-android) question on stackoverflow might be interesting. There are several technical difficulties to build such an application but the most difficult one might be that android doesn't support the A2DP mode by simply not letting you configure its A2DP to be a sink.

Considering that probably much more experienced users/developers (no offense!) gave up this approach, it might be easier for you to get your WiFi working properly. There are several possibilities to fix a weak WiFi signal (adjust the antenna of AP and Client, removing obsticals etc.).

Comment: then consider to mark it as answer ;)